# Google Map V2 android Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I used google map v2 in my android application, i created my api key in the google console.

But always i have this result in the emulator :

[image]

someone help me please ?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: i uploaded the picture this is always the result

Comment: I think you can't use a emulator with Google Maps API V2. Try again but only in a real device. Have you tried that already?

Comment: I seen many developer that run android apps which use the map v2

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have internet access with your simulator.

Then make sure you have the following in your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

And opengl2:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

[DOC HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#specifying_permissions)

If this is still not ok, then try to use [GENYMOTION](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator (with google apps).

Hope this will help you.